# Rails beginner config/routes.rb issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a little trouble understanding what config/routes actually routes to. For example lets say I started a brand new project and generated a Users controller and edited my config/routes.rb to look like this:

---

```
config/routes.rb

SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

end
```

---

I start the server and as expected, it says I don't have a "new" action in my Users controller. I create one:

---

```
 users_controller.rb

 class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def new
 end
```

---

I refresh the page and as expected it tells me I need a users/new template. So my question is: do my view templates always have to be the same as the controller and action names in "(controller name)/(action name)" format (in this case users/new.html.erb)? Is it not possible to name my template something random (e.g. users/rubyonrailsmeetup.html.erb instead of users/new.html.erb) if have a controller action linked to one of the site's functions?

Also, does adding "resources :users" to config/routes.rb by default match the view template file names with the behavior I mentioned above so that views must be named after their "controller/action" names?

Sorry for the bother, I'm just trying to figure out what's part of Rails' magic and what isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails attempts to render the template with the same name as the action by default, if no other `render` or `redirect` is invoked in the controller action. Basically, there's an implicit `render :action` at the end of every controller action.

But you can override this easily enough by adding an explicit render, e.g.,

```
render :rubyonrailsmeetup
```

Edit for clarity: this call to `render` goes in the controller code, not in config/routes

Comment: ooooo so it would be `match '/signup', to: 'users#new', render :users/rubyonrailsmeetup` to override the default, which is `render :users/new` in this case?

Comment: you can add the render line at the end of the action... if you want to override

Comment: ahhh I am starting to understand. thanks guys. so the config/routes goes to the controller first, and if there is no `render` in the action, then by default it just goes to the views with the filename "(controller)/(action).html.erb" correct?

Comment: Yep, you got it. Also, a redirect will prevent it from rendering that template as well (as you'd probably expect).

Comment: Also, it's just `render :rubyonrailsmeetup` if the view `rubyonrailsmeetup.html.erb` is in /views/users -- you don't need to specify that it's a users template. You *can*, however, render a view from a directory that isn't users by specifying the path (relative to /views/), e.g., `render 'events/rubyonrailsmeetup'` would look for views/events/rubyonrailsmeetup.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

> do my view templates always have to be the same as the controller and action names in "(controller name)/(action name)" format

These are **defaults**, you can render any view from the action by giving `render :view_file_rel_path` at the end of the **action**

> does adding "resources :users" to config/routes.rb by default match the view template file names

Anything added in **routes.rb** is directly related upto controllers only, i.e. it matches the request and maps it to the controller/action. Logic of view comes only inside the action code

Comment: but a lot of the time the actions in the controller are left blank (e.g. for static pages that require no interaction with the database). so in those cases the view would be determined by the "default" you're meaning right?

Comment: yup the view to be rendered is always determined by the default i.e. 'controller_name/action_name.html' unless you have written `render` explicitly in your action..